# This for loop codes leads to infinite loop, kills my terminal and console in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

I want to make a function that takes in two parameters, one is a number and the other is a function that generates random number, 0 or 1.
The purpose of this function is to generate a random array consists of 0 or 1. (example : [0,1,0,0,1] or [1,1,0,1,0,1,0]
But everytime I declare this function and try to use it, the terminal or console doesn't respond and dies immediately.
I think there's something wrong with for loop and it adds same random number to the array for infinite times  thus leads to shutdown.
How can I fix this?

Additional information :
I'm currently using node.js, and running codes with node commands in vscode powershell terminal.
I'm using external library for random number generation function, which returns random integers within desired range. To simulate the same situation on browser console, I made a function with Math.round(Math.random()) and result was the same. (it killed the console.)
The object answerSetter is used on different class as an imported function.

```js
const answerSetter = {
  getZeroOnes(size, generateRandomNumber) {
    const zeroOnes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size, i += 1;) {
      const randomNumber = generateRandomNumber
      zeroOnes.push(randomNumber);
    };
    return zeroOnes;
  },
};
```

I tried using break statement to break the loop.
`if(array.length = number){break;)` 
Then it breaks the loop, but the loop returns an array consists of same numbers like [0,0,0,0,0] or [1,1,1,1,1].

Comment: how is the function called

Comment: Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately. Relevant linter warning: _“Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.”_.

Comment: `generateRandomNumber()`

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < size,` <<< comma

Answer (score -1):

Straight forward, this is the correct code:

```js
const answerSetter = {
  getZeroOnes(size, _) {
    const zeroOnes = [];
    for (let i of Array(size)) {
      zeroOnes.push(_());
    };
    return zeroOnes;
  },
}
```

you may run it like this:

```
answerSetter.getZeroOnes(5, () => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0)
```

Now let's break this down.

the function `getZeroOnes()` accepts takes two arguments:

- The desired size of the result array
- the function to generate a random number

though i think that the second parameter is unnecessary as there is no need of a separate function to generate a random number being passed every time you need to use it.

To generate a random no. we can simply use a condition:

```js
Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
```

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between `0` and `1`.

so the condition: `Math.random() > 0.5` holds a 50% chance of being `true` and also a 50% chance of being `false`.

so accordingly we return values:

- `0` => if condition is false
- `1` => if condition is true

so we now have a way of generating random number which could either be `0` or `1`.

so we can modify our code:

```js
const answerSetter = {
  getZeroOnes(size) {
    const zeroOnes = [];
    for (let i of Array(size)) {
      zeroOnes.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0);
    };
    return zeroOnes;
  },
}
```

now let's come to the loop.
as you can see i have replaced the `for()` loop with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

using the [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) constructor we create an array of the `size` we received through the parameters.

so now the loop runs through every item of the array. i.e, it will run `n` number of times based on the `size` parameter.

now coming inside the loop, we just [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the random number inside the `zeroOnes` array.

now after the loop ends, we have an array with `n` number of items (with value of either `0` or `1`) based on the `size` parameter.

so we just return the resultant array at the end of our function.

if you try to run it:

```js
const answerSetter = {
  getZeroOnes(size) {
    const zeroOnes = [];
    for (let i of Array(size)) {
      zeroOnes.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0);
    };
    return zeroOnes;
  },
}

console.log(answerSetter.getZeroOnes(5))
```

we receive our desired output!